# Why is it important to protect the main loop when using joblib.Parallel?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

The joblib docs contain the following warning:

> Under Windows, it is important to protect the main loop of code to
>   avoid recursive spawning of subprocesses when using joblib.Parallel.
>   In other words, you should be writing code like this:
>
> ```
> import ....
>
> def function1(...):
>     ...
>
> def function2(...):
>     ...
>
> ... if __name__ == '__main__':
>     # do stuff with imports and functions defined about
>     ...
> ```
>
> No code should run outside of the “if __name__ == ‘__main__’” blocks,
>   only imports and definitions.

Initially, I assumed this was just to prevent against the occasional odd case where a function passed to `joblib.Parallel` called the module recursively, which would mean it was generally good practice but often unnecessary. However, it doesn't make sense to me why this would only be a risk on Windows. Additionally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029356/3204472) seems to indicate that failure to protect the main loop resulted in the code running several times slower than it otherwise would have for a very simple non-recursive problem.

Out of curiosity, I ran the super-simple example of an embarrassingly parallel loop from the joblib docs without protecting the main loop on a windows box. My terminal was spammed with the following error until I closed it:

```
ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not suppo
rt forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect you main loop using "if __name__ == '__main__'". Ple
ase see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information
```

**My question is,** what about the windows implementation of joblib requires the main loop to be protected in every case?

Apologies if this is a super basic question. I am new to the world of parallelization, so I might just be missing some basic concepts, but I couldn't find this issue discussed explicitly anywhere.

Finally, I want to note that this is purely academic; I understand why it is [generally good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to write one's code in this way, and will continue to do so regardless of joblib.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is necessary because Windows doesn't have `fork()`. Because of this limitation, Windows needs to re-import your `__main__` module in all the child processes it spawns, in order to re-create the parent's state in the child. This means that if you have the code that spawns the new process at the module-level, it's going to be recursively executed in all the child processes. The `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard is used to prevent code at the module scope from being re-executed in the child processes.

This isn't necessary on Linux because it *does* have `fork()`, which allows it to fork a child process that maintains the same state of the parent, without re-importing the `__main__` module.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I have to say, if I were designing an operating system, I would think the ability to fork processes would be pretty basic and desirable... but I guess this is just another curious limitation of windows.

Answer (score 9):

In case someone stumbles across this in 2021:
Due to the new backend "loky" used by joblib>0.12 protecting the main for loop is no longer required. See https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html