# multiprocessing python code

Tags: python, multiprocessor, joblib

When I try to paralellize python code I get an assertion error. Here is the code :

```
check = Parallel(n_jobs=ncpu)(delayed(removeident)(h) for h in splitframe)
```

individually, each element (h) in splitframe works well with the function *removeident* that is `removeident(h)` yields expected results.

The error message is on the console :

```
AssertionError: _ _main_ _
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>"; line 1, in <module>
   File"C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py"; line 380, in main prepare  (preparation_data)
   File"C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py"; line 488, in prepare assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: What error? Where's the traceback?

Comment: I run the code on ipython (jupiter) on the console I get the following error :

Comment: I run the code on ipython (jupiter) and on the console I get the following error that prints out repetivtely:     AssertionError : _ _main_ _

Comment: Edit the error into the question.

Comment: See [Why is it important to protect the main loop when using joblib.Parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545605/why-is-it-important-to-protect-the-main-loop-when-using-joblib-parallel)