# Grid search error

Tags: python, grid-search

I've been trying to perform a grid search, but something seems to be off.
My code is:

```
grid_search_0 = GridSearchCV(estimator=Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), ('clf', LinearSVC())]),
             param_grid={'C': 3**np.arange(-3, 3, dtype='float'),
                         'gamma': 3**np.arange(-6, 0, dtype='float'), },
             cv=10,
             scoring=make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_threshold=True),
             verbose=1,
             n_jobs=-1,)
```

and I get the error

`ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using "if __name__ == '__main__'". Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information`

Has anyone encountered and solved this before? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it important to protect the main loop when using joblib.Parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545605/why-is-it-important-to-protect-the-main-loop-when-using-joblib-parallel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the error message suggests doing, does this work for you?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    grid_search_0 = GridSearchCV(estimator=Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), ('clf', LinearSVC())]),
             param_grid={'C': 3**np.arange(-3, 3, dtype='float'),
                         'gamma': 3**np.arange(-6, 0, dtype='float'), },
             cv=10,
             scoring=make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_threshold=True),
             verbose=1,
             n_jobs=-1)
```

for more on why this is important, see [this Stack Overflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545605/why-is-it-important-to-protect-the-main-loop-when-using-joblib-parallel)

Comment: I have this problem while using jupyter so this does not solve the problem

Comment: @Simon, do you get the same error as the questioner here, or a different error message in jupyter? If you post a SO question with your issue and link to it here, I'll take a look.

Comment: I think it was an issue with an older version of joblib, seems to work in 0.12. If it re-occurs I will post a new question