# Python - Loop parallelisation with joblib

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, joblib

I would like some help understanding exactly what I have done/ why my code isn't running as I would expect.

I have started to use joblib to try and speed up my code by running a (large) loop in parallel.

I am using it like so:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def frame(indeces, image_pad, m):

    XY_Patches = np.float32(image_pad[indeces[0]:indeces[0]+m, indeces[1]:indeces[1]+m,  indeces[2]])
    XZ_Patches = np.float32(image_pad[indeces[0]:indeces[0]+m, indeces[1],                  indeces[2]:indeces[2]+m])
    YZ_Patches = np.float32(image_pad[indeces[0],                 indeces[1]:indeces[1]+m,  indeces[2]:indeces[2]+m])

    return XY_Patches, XZ_Patches, YZ_Patches


def Patch_triplanar_para(image_path, patch_size):

    Image, Label, indeces =  Sampling(image_path)

    n = (patch_size -1)/2
    m = patch_size

    image_pad = np.pad(Image, pad_width=n, mode='constant', constant_values = 0)

    A = Parallel(n_jobs= 1)(delayed(frame)(i, image_pad, m) for i in indeces)
    A = np.array(A)
    Label = np.float32(Label.reshape(len(Label), 1))
    R, T, Y =  np.hsplit(A, 3)

    return R, T, Y, Label
```

I have been experimenting with "n_jobs", expecting that increasing this will speed up my function. However as I increase n_jobs, things slow down quite significantly. When running this code without "Parallel", things are slower, until I increase the number of jobs from 1.

Why is this the case? I understood that the more jobs I run, the faster the script? am i using this wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: First, how many CPUs or cores do you have in the computer you run this?  
Second, `n_jobs` sets the maximum number of concurrently running jobs. Have you tried `n_jobs=-1`? This should use all the CPUs in your computer.
Third, how big is this `indeces` of your for loop?

Comment: I have 24 cores and a huge amount of memory. indeces has roughly 10,000 entries so had thought this would be a good thing to parallelise. I can try n_jobs=-1 and report back.

Comment: Yes. I can imagine that if you increase n_jobs from 1 to the max (n_jobs=23, njobs = -1) then you will reach a point in which incrementing this number will involve more overhead so you have to find a sweet spot. Of course if you can use the backend="threading" might be maybe better but you have to experiment.

Comment: Then, I would like to suggest this SO post, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027477/joblib-parallel-multiple-cpus-slower-than-single](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027477/joblib-parallel-multiple-cpus-slower-than-single) which has really good answers, and one of them directly from joblib author, although might be obsolete...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your problem is caused because `image_pad` is a large array. In your code, you are using the default `multiprocessing` backend of `joblib`. This backend creates a pool of workers, each of which is a Python process. The input data to the function is then copied `n_jobs` times and broadcasted to each worker in the pool, which can lead to a serious overhead. Quoting from [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#working-with-numerical-data-in-shared-memory-memmaping)'s docs:

> By default the workers of the pool are real Python processes forked using the multiprocessing module of the Python standard library when n_jobs != 1. The arguments passed as input to the Parallel call are serialized and reallocated in the memory of each worker process.
>
> This can be problematic for large arguments as they will be reallocated n_jobs times by the workers.
>
> As this problem can often occur in scientific computing with numpy based datastructures, joblib.Parallel provides a special handling for large arrays to automatically dump them on the filesystem and pass a reference to the worker to open them as memory map on that file using the numpy.memmap subclass of numpy.ndarray. This makes it possible to share a segment of data between all the worker processes.
>
> Note: The following only applies with the default "multiprocessing" backend. If your code can release the GIL, then using backend="threading" is even more efficient.

So if this is your case, you should switch to the threading backend, if you are able to release the global interpreter lock when calling `frame`, or switch to the shared memory approach of `joblib`.

The [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#automated-array-to-memmap-conversion) say that `joblib` provides an automated `memmap` conversion that could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible that the problem you are running up against is a fundamental one to the nature of the python compiler.

If you read "https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Python_Is_Not_C?lang=en", you can see from a professional who specialises in optimisation and parallelising python code that iterating through large loops is an inherently slow operation for a python thread to perform. Therefore, spawning more processes that loop through arrays is only going to slow things down.

However - there are things that can be done.

The [Cython](http://cython.org) and [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org) compilers are both designed to optimise code that is similar to C/C++ style (i.e. your case) - in particular Numba's new [@vectorise](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) decorators allow scalar functions to take in and apply operations on large arrays with large arrays in a parallel manner (`target=Parallel`).

I don't understand your code enough to give an example of an implementation, but try this! These compilers, used in the correct ways, have brought speed increases of 3000,000% to me for parallel processes in the past!